# Firebase Analytics - Where to find new users?

Tags: firebase-analytics

Coming from Fabric, I expected to be able to see how many new, unique users I have on my mobile apps, every day... But I can't find them on Firebase!

Is there anything I should do code-wise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the Analytics tab, look under Events and the first_open event which is automatically tracked by Firebase will show the number of users opening your app for the first time on each day.

Comment: When you say `on each day`, does it mean the same user on each day? So if user A registers today and opens the app every day, will he be included on the `first_open` events on each day, or on the first one only?

Comment: No, only on the first one - the first time he opens the app.